# Numbered/Ordered Lists in Panels - Twitter Bootstrap 3

Tags: list, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using list groups in panels for my FAQ.  Many of these lists are ordered and sequential instruction sets, and I would like the number to show up for a variety of reasons.  It seems, however, that even an ordered list becomes an unordered list when wrapped as a list-group.  Has anyone already overcome this?  It seems like an oversight to me.

I have tried manually setting:

- list-style: decimal
- list-style-poition: inside

Other thoughts?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4NtVR/

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">Test</div>
        <ol class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item">Item 1</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Item 2</li>
        </ol>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't currently have bootstrap , so a link to that portion or jsfiddle might help.

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#panels-list-group

The relevant Bootstrap info.

@AbhinavGauniyal

Comment: Okay , firebug accepts the 'list-style:square' property being applied , but still they don't show up. Even applying !important dosen't shows them up. Bookmarked for now , will post if something works.

Comment: I'm at least glad to know it's not just me. Thanks for putting in the time @AbhinavGauniyal

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Got a working solution for any else that need this:

http://jsfiddle.net/jschavey/4NtVR/2/

```
ol li.list-group-item { 
    list-style: decimal inside;
    display: list-item;
}
```